# Max-width not breaking single words, exceeding max-width

Tags: html, css

When using `max-width` why won't it "break" words that are longer than allowed and how would I go about making it work?

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rfo7y3om/3/)**

```js
function input() {
  var inputText = document.getElementById("inputField").value;
  document.getElementById("changingParagraph").innerHTML = inputText;
}
```

```css
#changingParagraph {
  max-width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="inputField" oninput="input()">
<p id="changingParagraph">
</p>
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The `<p>` is not exceeding the `max-width` length that you have set. The issue is that the text is overflowing so it goes past the length you set for your element. There are a few different methods for breaking text to the next line.

---

Using `overflow-wrap: break-word;` (previously known as `word-wrap: break-word`):

- will wrap overflowed words onto the the next line.
- will only break a word if its length exceeds the length of the container.

```js
function input() {
  var inputText = document.getElementById("inputField").value;
  document.getElementById("changingParagraph").innerHTML = inputText;
}
```

```css
#changingParagraph {
  max-width: 100px;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="inputField" oninput="input()">
<p id="changingParagraph">
</p>
```

---

Using `word-break: break-all`:

- will break when the content hits the specified width, even if the text is a single word.

```js
function input() {
  var inputText = document.getElementById("inputField").value;
  document.getElementById("changingParagraph").innerHTML = inputText;
}
```

```css
#changingParagraph {
  max-width: 100px;
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="inputField" oninput="input()">
<p id="changingParagraph">
</p>
```

---

For the most readable and clean looking breaks, `overflow-wrap: break-word;` is the best option.

Comment: This almost works, but instead of linebreaking, it hides the text. Is there another way, or is this the best it gets?