# How to automatically break line in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a piece of text like the below one which in order to view the whole
text I need to scroll to the end.

```
Hello, this is a piece of text and it is going beyond the screen width and I need scroll to view the whole piece of text which is not so comfortable....
```

I want it to automatically break the line when the screen width ends, for example, I want to display it on a mobile phone like the below example automatically

```
Hello, this is a piece of text
and it is going beyond the screen
width and I need scroll
to view the whole piece of text
which is not so comfortable....
```

Any idea how to do this?

Comment: Use CSS Media Queries

Comment: @Bishan I don't know them. Can you tell me? I mean for the text there

Comment: I usually set a `max-width: 100%` rule for an element that contains text. And it works. But you better show your code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Auto break line in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5852700/auto-break-line-in-html)

Comment: @sergeykuznetsov My code contains Django variables so you cannot see the text until you open it in the browser

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39211155/max-width-not-breaking-single-words-exceeding-max-width

Answer (score 0):

You should read about [HTML Responsive Web Design](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_responsive.asp).

Responsive Web Design is about using HTML and CSS to automatically resize, hide, shrink, or enlarge, a website, to make it look good on all devices (desktops, tablets, and phones)

Here's how we create a media query in CSS. This CSS block will only be applied if the width of the screen is less than 768 pixels.

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .container {
        width: 100%
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope, you are not missing `meta` viewport tag in `<head>`

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`

This gives the browser instructions on how to control the page's dimensions and scaling.

The `width=device-width` part sets the width of the page to follow the screen-width of the device (which will vary depending on the device).

The `initial-scale=1.0` part sets the initial zoom level when the page is first loaded by the browser.

The CSS for wrapping text will work with `white-space` as follow.

Hope this will be somehow useful to you.

```css
.nowrap{
  width:300px; /*Dont really required*/
  white-space:nowrap;
}
.wrap{
  width:300px; /*Dont really required*/
  white-space:normal; 
}
```

```html
<div class="nowrap">
Hello, this is a piece of text and it is going beyond the screen width and I need scroll to view the whole piece of text which is not so comfortable....
</div>
<br/>
<div class="wrap">Hello, this is a piece of text and it is going beyond the screen width and I need scroll to view the whole piece of text which is not so comfortable....</div>
```

Comment: Thanks buddy! This worked! I can't upvote cause my reputation is less than 15

Comment: No problem, Glad it helped

Answer (score 0):

You should use the CSS `word break` property. It adjusts the text according to the size of your container. Here is a runnable snippet:

```css
.container {
  width: 20%;
  height: 20%;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

.container-two {
  word-break: break-all;
  width: 20%;
  height: 20%;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    Thisissometextwhichwillnotfitinsidethediv.
  </div><br><br>
  <div class="container-two">
    Thisissometextwhichwillfitinsidethedivduetoaproperty.
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```